# Adding an Object to StringBuilder

Tags: java, android

I'm pretty new to Android development, and what I'm trying to do is display the contents of an `ArrayList` in a `TextView`.

I've been attempting to convert the `ArrayList` into an `Array`, and then append each item to a `StringBuilder`. However, the `StringBuilder` doesn't appear to allow me to append an `Object` from the `Array`. Can anyone tell me why, or in fact provide a better solution?

```java
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
    temp = data.getStringArrayListExtra("intentReturn");
    Object obj[] = temp.toArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
        sBuilder.append((String)obj[i]); //This is the line which crashes the app
        if(i < obj.length - 1){
            sBuilder.append(", ");
        }
    }
    tvResult.setText(sBuilder.toString());
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just use `obj[i].toString()`? And instead of creating a new array, just use `temp.get(i).toString()`, also using `temp.size()` instead of `obj.length`?

Comment: Apparently I forgot to add `StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();`... silly newbie!

Your suggestions @Jeffrey are much simpler than my over complicated rubble. Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome. Next time it might be wise to mention that you're getting a compiler error as opposed to a runtime exception, I had just assumed `sBuilder` was a field and that you were getting a `ClassCastException` when you tried to cast `obj[i]` (this sort of mistake happens rather frequently).

Comment: I apologise for the confusion. Perhaps I also should have included more code to distinguish. I really appreciate your feedback :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I forgot to add `StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();` - silly newbie! Thanks to Jeffrey for his code clean up too, much appreciated!

In order to provide a sufficient answer, here is my new code:

```java
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
    temp = data.getStringArrayListExtra("intentReturn");
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++){
        sBuilder.append(temp.get(i).toString());
        if(i < temp.size() - 1){
            sBuilder.append(", ");
        }
    }
    tvResult.setText(sBuilder.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your sBuilder append line to this:

```
sBuilder.append(obj[i].toString());
```

That way you're not trying to cast an Object to a String, but rather getting the Object's String representation.

[The documentation for Object.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

**1.** I **did NOT** understood your reason to **convert** the `ArrayList to Array`.

**2.** Try it this way... **I am directly appending String from ArrayList to the StringBuilder, using For-Each Loop**

**Eg:**

```
for (String te : temp){
    sBuilder.append(te);
}
```

Comment: I am still rather new to both Java and Android and have already been informed of this redundancy. Thank you for your feedback.